# Povray: Can an object only interact with some light sources?

Tags: raytracing, povray

Consider a sphere, with a "spotlight" light source inside. I would like the sphere not to interact with that particular "spotlight" lightsource, but it should interact with all the other light sources. I know that this is not realistical, I would just need it for a nice picture. 
Is this possible in povray?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the concept of light groups.  But everything else in a light_group except the sphere.

http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.7.0/320/

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I still cannot see that the light of the spotlights inside the sphere comes out of the sphere.

Comment: Okay, please offer simplified version of code you're trying, and I'll see if I can get it all the way home